# dplyr - Filter a data frame using a value sampled from a column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filtering

I am trying to randomly sample a single value from a column, and then filter the data frame based on that value.

This is what I have tried to do:

```
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(x = sample.int(50,100, replace = T),
                 y = rnorm(100))

df %>% 
  filter(x == sample(1, x))
```

However, it is not working. If the sampled number is let's say 39, the result I am expecting would be the same from:

```
df %>% 
  filter(x == 39)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to use `sample(x,1)`.  That is, the values to sample from come first, and the size (in this case 1) comes second.

Comment: It looks like you just have the order of your parameters reversed. It should be `df %>% filter(x == sample(x, 1))`